# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' CSS?

Tags: css, syntax-error

How is it possible, I don't even know what to ask here. I cannot add a "." on css?

[image]

Comment: I can't paste the CSS code into a validator because it's a picture but it looks correct. The important question is, what's the tool you're using to generate those messages? Is it configured correctly?

Comment: Because the css file needs to be included in the `link` tag, but not in the `script` tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You css file is being processed as a javascript file. Are you sure the file is being included as a css file as in:

```
<link href="yourstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and not

```
<script src="yourstyle.css"></script>
```

Comment: Man, two years ago you saved me today a lot of wasted time and frustration.